# Transact SQL Server 2000: query 1 to many from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

In the product table i have the following

```
Prod_code           Flashpack
9999                9999
1000                9999
1500                1500
2000                   0
2500                9999
3000                3000
3500                   0
```

What i would like to do is query Prod_Code where it equals Flashpack but also returning the prod_code
Example

```
Prod_code         Link1   link2 
9999               10000  2500
```

All help appriciated

Comment: Sql queries don't grow horizontally, they're supposed to grow vertically.

Comment: This will be painful in SQL Server 2000. You are doing a `PIVOT` query without anything to Pivot on. Is there a maximum number of columns even?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT 
    p1.prod_code, p2.*
FROM
    Product p1
    INNER JOIN Product p2 ON p1.prod_code = p2.flashpack
```